# Javascript: Why arguments are undefined when paused in a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, debugging

Why is it that when paused in a breakpoint, sometimes arguments are undefined?

```
function foo(arg1) {
  debugger;
  // arg1 is undefined in breakpoint
}

foo(123)
```

If the argument is set to another variable, that value is now available..

```
function foo(arg1) {
  const x = arg1;
  debugger;
  // arg1 is undefined in breakpoint
  // BUT, x is 123
}

foo(123)
```

Like most developers, I'm using a bundler (Webpack). 
My hunch is that this is due to minification / a flakey sourcemap, but I'm not sure.

Comment: must be browser specific, because  firefox certainly reports arg1 as having value 123 ... oh, wait, didn't see the mention of *minifaction*

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual minified code and compare it to the source - it's quite likely that Webpack decided to "help" you by removing the "unused" variable/argument :)